# How to implement Debug to struct with `RefCell<Vec<Weak<Gadget>>>` field type?

Tags: rust

code:

```
struct Owner {
    name: String,
    gadgets: RefCell<Vec<Weak<Gadget>>>,
}

//code omitted

impl fmt::Debug for Owner {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Owner {{ name: {}, gadgets: {:?} }}", self.name, self.gadgets.into_inner())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let gadget_owner : Rc<Owner> = Rc::new( Owner { /**/ });
    let gadget1 = gadget_owner.make_gadget(1);
    println!("gadget1 is: {:?}", gadget1);
}
```

bring error:

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
src/main.rs:25         write!(f, "Owner {{ name: {}, gadgets: {:?} }}", self.name, self.gadgets.into_inner())
                                                                                   ^~~~
```

[full code there](http://pastebin.com/jUYayJ3P)

Comment: Rather than adding a useless filler, why not tell us what you do not understand? Do you understand what ownership and borrowing are? Have you read the Rust Book? Have you read the documentation about [`RefCell::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.into_inner)?

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes, now I  see , I must borrow it at first, because into_inner() destroy RefCell

Comment: Exactly, and you will not be permitted to destroy the `RefCell` because you are only borrowing it. By the way, if you solved your issue, you might want to answer yourself :)

Comment: Thank you, I just little improve and publish it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add retreiving gadget ids

```
impl fmt::Debug for Owner {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let gadgets = self.gadgets.borrow();
        let ids: Vec<i32> = gadgets.iter()
                                   .map(|ref x| {
                                       x.upgrade()
                                        .unwrap()
                                        .id
                                   })
                                   .collect();
        write!(f, "Owner {{ name: {}, gadgets: {:?} }}", self.name, ids)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
gadget1 is: Gadget { id: 1, owner: Owner { name: Gadget Man, gadgets: [1, 2] } }
gadget2 is: Gadget { id: 2, owner: Owner { name: Gadget Man, gadgets: [1, 2] } }
```

[Full code there](https://gist.github.com/BjornMelgaard/bcc1f27d6cbaa3bab111acce16e564c4)