# ws::Sender doesn't implement std::fmt::Debug

Tags: rust

I have a connection type `Cons` and a `Subscriber` implementation for my Redis server. ws is a websocket library. There's no chance to edit source code either:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Consumer {
    tag: String,
    no_local: bool,
    no_ack: bool,
    exclusive: bool,
    nowait: bool,
    subscriber: Box<ConsumerSubscriber>,
    pub current_message: Option<bool>,
}

impl Consumer {
    pub fn new(
        tag: String,
        no_local: bool,
        no_ack: bool,
        exclusive: bool,
        nowait: bool,
        subscriber: Box<ConsumerSubscriber>,
    ) -> Consumer {
        Consumer {
            tag,
            no_local,
            no_ack,
            exclusive,
            nowait,
            subscriber,
            current_message: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn new_delivery_complete(&mut self) {
        if let Some(delivery) = self.current_message.take() {
            self.subscriber.new_delivery(delivery);
        }
    }
}

pub trait ConsumerSubscriber: Debug + Send + Sync {
    fn new_delivery(&mut self, delivery: bool);
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Sender {
    connection_id: u32,
}

// Above code is out of my source code and I cannot edit it.
// Below is my own code.

type Cons = Arc<Mutex<HashMap<u64, Sender>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Subscriber {
    messager: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    connections: Cons,
}

impl ConsumerSubscriber for Subscriber {
    fn new_delivery(&mut self, delivery: bool) {
        println!("received correctly: {:?}", delivery)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=48c8cf0e7647597d2ae25337698ab158&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: `Sender` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:58:5
   |
58 |     connections: Cons,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Sender` cannot be formatted using `{:?}`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `Sender`
   = note: add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement `std::fmt::Debug`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `std::collections::HashMap<u64, Sender>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `std::sync::Mutex<std::collections::HashMap<u64, Sender>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<std::collections::HashMap<u64, Sender>>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `&std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<std::collections::HashMap<u64, Sender>>>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::fmt::Debug`
```

If I remove the `#[derive(Debug)]` attribute on `Subscriber`, it complains about `Subscriber`. I cannot remove it, and I cannot compile with it.

How can I handle this error and pass connections `Cons` to this struct?

Comment: I have added to the question. Thanks and Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to implement a custom 'fmt::Debug' trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22243527/155423) and/or [How to implement Debug to struct with `RefCell<Vec<Weak<Gadget>>>` field type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36385519/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster, Those examples suggest me to change all code. However, I have no chance to edit whats out of my own source code. I have added comment to code to show what's mine and what's not.

Comment: *to change all code* — no, they don't. You just need to implement `Debug` for `Subscriber` instead of using `derive`.

Comment: May I ask a little help on my case. I tried to implement according to two links you post. However, with no luck. :/

Comment: "I tried to implement it and it worked". Note how this isn't a useful statement for me to make because you cannot tell what I did? Likewise, saying you tried but did not succeed in not useful. What did you try? What went wrong? Again, these are basic parts of creating a [MCVE].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement `Debug` as @Shepmaster suggested. You may want to go with a more useful implementation though I'm not sure from context what that would be.

```
impl fmt::Debug for Subscriber {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Hi")
    }
}
```

[playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=e95f0ab1aea888731b2d2c9867e421a5&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: Do you agree that this question is answered by the linked questions then?

Comment: Yes, although this answer is distinct in some sense with the link to working implementation of questioners code